# Nested DIVs - How to make it work for Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, html

Nested divs; works perfectly in Firefox-Opera-Safari, how to make it work for IE7?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <div id="test-div-two" style="border: 1px solid magenta; float:left; margin: 2px;">
    <div style="height: 20px; background: rgb(232,238,224); margin: 2px;">
    Heading
    </div>
    <div id="test-div-two-content" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; background: white; margin: 2px;">
    Scrillable&nbsp;content&nbsp;blaa<br/>
    Scrillable content content content <br/>
    Scrillable content <br/>
    Scrillable content blaa<br/>
    Scrillable content <br/>
    Scrillable content <br/>
    Scrillable content <br/>
    Scrillable content <br/>
    Scrillable content <br/>
    Scrillable content <br/>
    Scrillable content
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; background: rgb(238,238,238); margin: 2px;">
    <img src="grippie.png" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

What I want: minimum width, that's why I use float. I am building a custom "drop down menu" and I don't want it to expand to the whole page and I want it to fit the longest string.

In my own IE7 browser it stretches and fills the whole page. In all other browsers (FF,Safari,Opera, probably ie8) it works nicely and fits to "minimum width".

Comment: I don't think nested `<div />` tags is the issue here. I think it has more to do with your CSS.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? I tried it in IE8 (compatibility view) and Firefox and both look fine (except that the table in IE spans the whole width of the page).

Comment: XHTML 1.0 Transitional

The problem is exactly that "in IE spans the whole width of the page". That's not what I want.

Comment: BTW: I added the <img/> tag there it seems to make a difference to the worse. I need the grippie to be centered.

Answer (score 2):

“Work”? What's the exact issue with it?

For me, it renders mostly the same as Firefox et al in IE7, as long as the document has a suitable [Standards Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) DOCTYPE. I do see a problem where it adds a horizontal scrollbar, which you can fix by adding something like `overflow-x: hidden; padding-right: 24px;` on the content div.

(The problem being that by doing a `float` without an explicit `width`, you have asked for shrink-to-fit-content-width behaviour, but the exact content width is dependent on whether there's a scrollbar on the content div, which IE can't know without knowing if the content scrolls, which is in turn dependent on the parent's content-width. This catch-22 is why IE gets confused; in Quirks Mode it totally gives up and makes the float full-width. This is why shrink-to-fit floats should be used with caution. If you set an explicit width on the floated element there would be no difficulty.)

Comment: Shrink-fit is what I need. I would like to make it work with ie7 and XHTML 1.0 Transitional (otherwise I will have to change the whole web app dtd).

Comment: XHTML 1.0 Transitional is a perfectly good Standards Mode doctype, yeah. Check you are putting it right at the top of the document with no other content before it. Do `javascript:alert(document.compatMode)` to see if it has taken (should be `CSS1Compat`).

Comment: Ofcourse ; ) Does it work for your ie7? Note the img tag at the bottom with display: block  (to center it)

Comment: Why the `display: block` shenanigans? Surely just a normal image with `text-align: center` on the parent `div` would be easiest?

Comment: In FF it makes no difference whether it is display: block  or text-align center. But in ie7, again, the text-align center makes the footer div much taller than the img. It doesn't look ok with that.

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="test-div-two">` is a floated div without an explicit width. I think browsers are free to interpret the width any way they want in this case.

If you specify a width (e.g. `width:50px;`), it looks the same on all browsers.

Comment: In CSS 2.0 a float without width would have the same width as a non-float, ie. it would be full width minus border and padding. However, only IE5/Mac actually did this; other browsers did various versions of shrink-to-fit, which CSS 2.1 then made standard (though not in a wholly well-defined way).

Comment: BTW: I added the <img/> tag there it seems to make a difference to the worse. I need the grippie to be centered.